# javac - Generating platform specific binary code

Tags: java, jvm, javac, jvm-hotspot

JVM involves,

1) Compiler threads compiling byte code to native code at runtime.

2) Linking phase similar to linking of `.o` files into executable(like C)

Compilation and Dynamic linking is **not a one time job**, after jvm is initially launched. This is part of life-cycle of an executable, running on production.

Why java compiler designed to generate platform independent code(byte code)? that shifts performance lag to java runtime with compilation of byte code & Linking capabilities, on every production machine.

Aren't we utilizing an extra bunch of cpu cycles for processing(compilation/linking) at runtime on every production machine, that customer owns? Customer does not need to be aware about **compile once and run everywhere**, which can be avoided with 2-3 build machines, to build platform specific binaries.

Comment: A JVM does *not* compile byte code to C code. Neither will there be any `.o` file. The compilation done by the JVM has nothing to do with the C programming language or how C programs are linked. Besides that, try to think about why web pages are delivered as html that has to be parsed, processed and finally rendered by a browser, instead of delivering executable binaries that do the rendering directly.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Below is an answer to the original question interpreted as "*What can be done to minimize the impact of Just-In-Time compilation on the Java Virtual Machine?*"

## Use interpreter only

If you want to disable compilation altogether you can use `java`'s `-Xint` argument. However I think that this will result in a significant performance degradation in almost all cases.

## Reduce JIT compiler threads priority

You can reduce the priority of the JIT compiler threads using `-XX:CompilerThreadPriority=<n>`. The values you can use there are OS-dependent.

## Reduce number of JIT compiler threads

If you are concerned by the number of JIT compiler threads, you can use the `-XX:CICompilerCount=<n>` and `-XX:[+|-]CICompilerCountPerCPU` flags to control the number of compiler threads.

- If `CICompilerCountPerCPU` is true (`-XX:+CICompilerCountPerCPU`), HotSpot will use some formula to decide how many compiler thread should be started (~ (log n * log log n) * 3 / 2 where n = # of available CPUs).
- If `CICompilerCount` is set HotSpot will use that many compiler threads.

If you don't set anything, `CICompilerCountPerCPU` will automatically be set to true.

## Tweak compilation policies

You can increase the compilation thresholds so that less methods get compiled. If you are using tired-compilation (the default nowadays) you can use

- `-XX:Tier3CompileThreshold=<n>` (defaults to 2000)
- `-XX:Tier3InvocationThreshold=<n>` (defaults to 200)
- `-XX:Tier4CompileThreshold=<n>` (defaults to 15000)
- `-XX:Tier4InvocationThreshold=<n>` (defaults to 5000)

The tiered compilation policy has many other knobs.
In particular you can also only use some of the tiers with `-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=<n>` where n is between 1 and 4. Higher tiers generally provide better performance but require longer compilation times.

Answer (score 0):

The reason Java doesn't generate platform-specific executables is because of portability. The point of Java is "write once, run anywhere." One should be able to write a java program on a windows computer, compile it on a Linux, and run it on a Mac, with no problem whatsoever. The person(s) who write the JVM for the target platform are the ones doing the work of porting it to a the new platform, not you.

But the JVM is really good at optimizing, and can translate heavily used code from byte-code to platform-specific native code. It only does this where needed, if it will improve performance. Like an optimizing compiler, the JVM knows best, and don't undermine its capabilities unless you have a **specific** use case.

Comment: `javac` gave portability to users at a cost of performing platform specific stuff(mentioned in query) at runtime, using jvm. For this, we need to install platform specific java runtime(jvm).

Comment: @overexchange But let's say I write a cool app in Java. I use a windows computer, and don't have a Mac/Linux to compile on. If I use a language that is compiled to platform specific code, only windows computers could use my program. But because of this, anyone can use my code

Comment: For me, having a platform specific `javac` looks to be a  better solution. That does not mean, programmer need to write platform specific java code. It is the same job that `javac` what jvm does at runtime to detect platform specific decisions for generating platform specific binary

Comment: @overexchange I understand that, but that means that I have to compile my code on a Windows PC, MacOS, and Linux. As a developer, I can write code for anywhere, and compile it only once

Comment: If build process with 2-3 extra machines is more costlier/serious than compromising runtime performance lags, on every production machine(jvm) that byte code compiles. Not sure, what is the point here?

Comment: @overexchange you mean so be it? Anyway, the compromise isn't that much

Comment: Isn't that much? you are adding an extra layer of processing(compilation/linking) at runtime on every production machine, that customer owns. Instead of deploying a platform specific binary.

Comment: @overexchange well you still technically need the JVM to organize garbage collection, native code, and multi threading... so it would be infeasable to package the entire JVM in every executable

Comment: JDK 9, which is released today by the way, includes an experimental AOT (ahead of time) compiler. See JEP for more information http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295 and this JVMLS talk for performance numbers https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5DCg6M2MDM&list=PLX8CzqL3ArzXJ2EGftrmz4SzS6NRr6p2n&index=11